# How to sum data if it falls under any arbitrary number of date ranges

Tags: date, google-sheets, sumifs

I need a single formula for summing numbers that fall within an arbitrary number of date ranges.

You can use multiple `SUMIFS()` for each date range and then sum the result of those `SUMIFS()`s within a single cell like this:

```
=SUMIFS(dataRange, datesRange,">="&startDate, D:D,"<="&endDate) + 
 SUMIFS(dataRange, datesRange,">="&startDate, D:D,"<="&endDate) + 
 SUMIFS(dataRange, datesRange,">="&startDate, D:D,"<="&endDate)
```

But this requires that I know exactly how many date ranges I'm going to have. 
For my spreadsheet I won't know how many date ranges I will have, so it has to dynamically grab the dates ranges.

[Sample Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E58Txn7TghZkv2riQLvIw3jYkFOsW0i1L5ivZRPlL_Y/edit?usp=sharing) (currently editable, please feel free to use)

Comment: I was playing around with your spreadsheet and I created a named range named AllDates G4:G.  Then I used that named for creating validation for your dateranges and now you can pick the date ranges much easier I think. You can always remove it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIF` in conjunction with the `SUMPRODUCT` function that multiplies components in the given arrays, and returns the sum of those products.

This can be done as below:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,">="&A4:A100,D:D,"<="&B4:B100))
```

Comment: It looks like this formula only grabs the first pair of dates. It also seems to have the same behavior as ``` =ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(E:E,D:D,">="&A4:A100,D:D,"<="&B4:B100)) ```

For whatever reason, `SUMIFS()` isn't taking a range for it's conditionals, it's only getting the first pair of dates.

Comment: it worked for me. check this [xlsx file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6lmStnVCjiIZlZZOEl4Nkp2YWM/view?usp=sharing). though i agree with you that sometime the behavior is unpredictable

Comment: @curious Very strange. It doesn't work for me. Both `SUMPRODUCT(…)` and `ARRAYFORMULA(…)` return 2133.83, whilst the internal `SUMIFS(…)` returns 876.03. What does  `SUMIFS(…)` return for you? Can you let us know what it returns both in your copy of the sheet and ben's copy (already set up in the "Copy of Main" sheet).

Comment: @benlimpich Don't know about that. I only have an old version of Excel here (2007). It doesn't work in that. I guess we'll have to wait until curious replies.

Comment: hi robinCTS wud u try the xlsx file link i mentioned in my previous comment n let us know the outcome? hi benlimpich, looks like [SUMPRODUCT behaves differently in Excel and Google docs](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Gae-b_Z5hc4). hi @robinCTS i have Excel 2016 so can't test under Excel 2007, but i'll take your test result at face value as that wast was the 1st version when this function was introduced n might hv evolved a lot after that

Comment: Sorry, curious. Should have previously explained that when you click your xlsx file link, what you see *looks* correct. However, when you click the "Open with Google Sheets" button, the value changes to 2148.83. The original correct value makes sense if what is shown is a static preview of the xlsx file based on its last saved values. Can you confirm that when you edit your xlsx file in google sheets it also changes? Based on my testing it seems that the problem is with `SUMIFS()`. `ARRAYFORMULA()` doesn't actually turn `SUMIFS()` into an array formula, i.e., one that returns an array…

Comment: For example, `ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIFS(D:D,D:D,">="&A4:A100))` returns the same single value as `SUMIFS(D:D,D:D,">="&A4)`. Contrast this with `SUMIF()`  which *does* work correctly. `ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(D:D,">="&A4:A100)` returns an array just as you would expect. I have setup up these examples in the "Copy of Main" sheet of @benlimpich 's spreadsheet.

Comment: Oops! Just realized it *does* work in Excel 2007. Had the usual US vs Oz (and the rest of the world) date issue ;) This means you were right @benlimpich. curious' answer works in Excel but not in Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: yes in all probability that seems to be the case. there's quite a bit of discussion on this issue as per the link i mentioned in my last comment. apparently, [Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294?hl=en) formula uses 1-dimensional array algorithm, whereas [Excel](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e) has the capability to use 2-dimensional array. so on complex calculations, the result may differ